# Open ended peer version dependency for package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, semantic-versioning

### Summary

I'm presuming all major versions of `@angular/core` will work for this.  Should I specify the package peer dependency as:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "@angular/core": "x.x"
}
```

### Context

I'm creating a package for an angular service that will be published on NPM.  The module just contains a set of easing functions that should work with any version of angular.  Brief snippet included below for reference.  As you can see the service imports `Injectable` from `@angular/core`. I'm assuming it will be just as valid for major version 5, 6, 7 and so on.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class RoundProgressEase {
  // t: current time (or position) of the neonate. This can be seconds or frames, steps,
  // seconds, ms, whatever – as long as the unit is the same as is used for the total time.
  // b: beginning value of the property.
  // c: change between the beginning and destination value of the property.
  // d: total time of the neonate.

  linearEase(t: number, b: number, c: number, d: number): number {
    return c * t / d + b;
  };

  easeInQuad(t: number, b: number, c: number, d: number): number {
    return c * (t /= d) * t + b;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an open ended range you use the asterisk (*)

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "@angular/core": "*"
}
```